# how to set label width to widest element using nomencl?

Tags: spacing, nomenclature

Is it possible to set the `\nomlabelwidth` of the `nomencl` package to the widest element automatically?

The manual only gives the option of setting it at a fixed width as an argument to the `printbibliography`. That seems a little like trial and error to me.

Does anybody have an idea on how to achieve this automatically, if possible?

I have no MWE since it is not really that kind of a problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a method described in the [`nomencl` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/nomencl/nomencl.pdf), section 5.3: *"Using a Long Table instead of a List"*.

First of all, make a copy of `nomencl.ist` in your working directory and add the following lines at its end:

```
item_0  ""
delim_t " \\\\\n"
```

The path of the original file is `TEXMF\makeindex\nomencl` (run `kpsewhich nomencl.ist` from the command line if you're not sure where to find it).

Then, in your `.tex` file, load the package `longtable` and add the following lines in your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@@@nomenclature[#1]#2#3{%
  \def\@tempa{#2}\def\@tempb{#3}%
  \protected@write\@nomenclaturefile{}%
    {\string\nomenclatureentry{#1\nom@verb\@tempa @{\nom@verb\@tempa}&%
      \begingroup\nom@verb\@tempb\protect\nomeqref{\theequation}%
        |nompageref}{\thepage}}%
    \endgroup
  \@esphack}
\def\thenomenclature{%
  \@ifundefined{chapter}{\section*}{\chapter*}{\nomname}%
  \nompreamble
  \begin{longtable}[l]{@{}ll@{}}}
\def\endthenomenclature{%
  \end{longtable}%
  \nompostamble}  
\makeatother
```

Your `thenomenclature` environment is now a `longtable`environment instead of a list.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{longtable}

\makeatletter
\def\@@@nomenclature[#1]#2#3{%
  \def\@tempa{#2}\def\@tempb{#3}%
  \protected@write\@nomenclaturefile{}%
    {\string\nomenclatureentry{#1\nom@verb\@tempa @{\nom@verb\@tempa}&%
      \begingroup\nom@verb\@tempb\protect\nomeqref{\theequation}%
        |nompageref}{\thepage}}%
    \endgroup
  \@esphack}
\def\thenomenclature{%
  \@ifundefined{chapter}{\section*}{\chapter*}{\nomname}%
  \nompreamble
  \begin{longtable}[l]{@{}ll@{}}}
\def\endthenomenclature{%
  \end{longtable}%
  \nompostamble}  
\makeatother

\makenomenclature

\begin{document}

\[F=ma\]

\nomenclature{$F$}{Force}
\nomenclature{$a$}{Acceleration}
\nomenclature{$m$}{Mass}

\nomenclature{very long entry}{A very long entry}

\printnomenclature

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I didn't catch that in the manual. It did exactly what I wanted it to do.

Comment: @niclasericsson Happy about that!

Answer (score 0):

This answer extends **karlkoeller**'s answer. The method described in the [nomencl manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/nomencl/nomencl.pdf), section 5.3: *"Using a Long Table instead of a List"* is good in everything, except for two things:

1. It doesn't respect `intoc` option
2. It doesn't properly handle comments that don't fit in one line: i.e., no automatic line breaks

I looked at `nomencl.sty` to fix the former, and switched to `longtabu` environment, a modified `longtable` environment from [tabu](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabu) package, which supports `X` column type that breaks long lines properly, to fix the latter.

The first step is the same as the one from the [nomencl manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/nomencl/nomencl.pdf) (and **karlkoeller**'s answer). Make a copy of `nomencl.ist` in your working directory and add the following lines at its end:

```
item_0  ""
delim_t " \\\\\n"
```

The path of the original file is `TEXMF\makeindex\nomencl`.

Then, the part that I edited. In your `.tex` file, load packages `longtable` and `tabu` and add the following lines in your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@@@nomenclature[#1]#2#3{%
  \def\@tempa{#2}\def\@tempb{#3}%
  \protected@write\@nomenclaturefile{}%
    {\string\nomenclatureentry{#1\nom@verb\@tempa @{\nom@verb\@tempa}&%
      \begingroup\nom@verb\@tempb\protect\nomeqref{\theequation}%
        |nompageref}{\thepage}}%
    \endgroup
  \@esphack}
\def\thenomenclature{%
  \@ifundefined{chapter}%
  {
    \section*{\nomname}
    \if@intoc\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\nomname}\fi%
  }%
  {
    \chapter*{\nomname}
    \if@intoc\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\nomname}\fi%
  }%
  \nompreamble
  \begin{longtabu} to \textwidth {@{}lX@{}}}
\def\endthenomenclature{%
  \end{longtabu}
  \nompostamble}
\makeatother
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
\usepackage{longtable,tabu}

\makeatletter
\def\@@@nomenclature[#1]#2#3{%
  \def\@tempa{#2}\def\@tempb{#3}%
  \protected@write\@nomenclaturefile{}%
    {\string\nomenclatureentry{#1\nom@verb\@tempa @{\nom@verb\@tempa}&%
      \begingroup\nom@verb\@tempb\protect\nomeqref{\theequation}%
        |nompageref}{\thepage}}%
    \endgroup
  \@esphack}
\def\thenomenclature{%
  \@ifundefined{chapter}%
  {
    \section*{\nomname}
    \if@intoc\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\nomname}\fi%
  }%
  {
    \chapter*{\nomname}
    \if@intoc\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\nomname}\fi%
  }%
  \nompreamble
  \begin{longtabu} to \textwidth {@{}lX@{}}}
\def\endthenomenclature{%
  \end{longtabu}
  \nompostamble}
\makeatother

\makenomenclature

\begin{document}

\[F=ma\]

\tableofcontents{}

\nomenclature{$F$}{Force}
\nomenclature{$a$}{Acceleration}
\nomenclature{$m$}{Mass}

\nomenclature{very long entry}{A very long entry that is also large enough to not fit a single line, and so on, and so forth}

\printnomenclature

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]