# Increase spacing between text and symbol in Notations

Tags: spacing, nomenclature, scrbook

I am using scrbook package to write my report. I am defining the list of notations as follows:

```
\renewcommand{\nomname}{Notation}
\renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{R}}{%
\item[\textbf{Roman Symbols}]}{%           R - Roman
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{G}}{%
\item[\textbf{Greek Symbols}]}{%           G - Greek
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{S}}{%
\item[\textbf{Superscripts}]}{%            S - Superscripts
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{U}}{%
\item[\textbf{Subscripts}]}{%              U - Subscripts
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{X}}{%
\item[\textbf{Other Symbols}]}{%           X - Other Symbols
{}}}}}}}
\renewcommand*{\nompreamble}{\markboth{\nomname}{\nomname}}
\makenomenclature
```

I am using these commands in my text as follows:

```
\nomenclature[r]{$\mG_\mathrm{{ant}}$}{Antenna Gain [dB]}
\nomenclature[r]{$\mU(r,\theta,\phi)$}{Antenna Pattern in the Angular Domain}
 \printnomenclature
```

I am getting the output as 
[image: Example]

I would like to (1)increase the spacing between notation and text so that they look aligned and (2)decrease the spacing between two consecutive notations. I would highly appreciate if someone tells me how to do so.

Comment: Please give us something compilable.

Comment: For the first problem: `\setlength{\nomlabelwidth}{1.5cm}` (experiment for the best value); for the second problem, the manual suggests `\setlength{\nomitemsep}{-\parsep}`.

Comment: @egreg …aaand there's the answer.

Comment: @egreg would you please add this as an answer ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For the first problem, you can set

```
\setlength{\nomlabelwidth}{1.5cm}
```

in the preamble (adjust to the needed value), or follow the method suggested for [how to set label width to widest element using nomencl?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/262392/how-to-set-label-width-to-widest-element-using-nomencl) (a bit more complicated).

For the second problem, the manual of `nomencl` suggests

```
\setlength{\nomitemsep}{-\parsep}
```

(also in the document preamble).

Comment: Also, the `\nomlabelwidth` length can be set by using `\printnomenclature[1.5cm]`.